# Printing star shapes based on user input

Tags: c

In an interview I was asked to write a code for a function that accepts a number from user and prints asterisk shapes as stated below...

```
mraouf@mraouf-Inspiron-1525:~$ ./printStars 
Enter: 1
*
mraouf@mraouf-Inspiron-1525:~$ ./printStars 
Enter: 3
*
 *
*
mraouf@mraouf-Inspiron-1525:~$ ./printStars
Enter: 5
*
 *
* *
 *
*
mraouf@mraouf-Inspiron-1525:~$ ./printStars 
Enter: 7
*
 *
* *
 * *
* *
 *
*
mraouf@mraouf-Inspiron-1525:~$ ./printStars
Enter: 9
*
 *
* *
 * *
* * *
 * *
* *
 *
*
```

I did my best but I wasn't able to achieve the required result.. here is the code I wrote :

```
#include<stdio.h>

void printStars(int lines)
{
        int i,x;
        int half = (lines/2)+1;
        system("clear");
        for(i=1; i<half ; i++)
        {
                if ( i%2 == 0)
                {
                        printf(" ");
                }
                else
                {
                        printf("* ");
                }
                for(x=0; x<i-1; x++)
                {
                        printf("* ");
                }
                printf("\n");
        }
        for(i=half; i>0; i--)
        {
                if( i%2 == 0 )
                {
                        printf(" ");
                }
                for(x=i; x>0; x--)
                {
                        printf("* ");
                }
                printf("\n");
        }
}
int main (void)
{
        int num;
        printf("Enter:\n");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        printStars(num);
        return 0;
}
```

Any Idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code printed two characters as it iterated and it needed to print one character (either a space or a *).  This code keeps the flavor of your implementation, but produces the right results.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printStars(int lines)
{
        int i,x;
        int half = (lines/2)+1;
        system("clear");
        for(i=1; i<half ; i++)
        {
            for(x=i; x>0; x--)
            {
                if ( x%2 == 0)
                {
                    printf(" ");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("*");
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        for(i=half; i>0; i--)
        {
            for(x=i; x>0; x--)
            {
                if ( x%2 == 0)
                {
                    printf(" ");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("*");
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
}
int main (void)
{
        int num;
        printf("Enter:\n");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        printStars(num);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually this is a [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) of stars on vertical axis. If you notice that, you can solve this problem in an elegant way.

The distribution coefficient is defined as **n! / k! (n-k)!** where **k** successes can occur anywhere among the **n** trials. If you define a **recursive factorial function** in your code and implement the simple binomial distribution formula (refactor your code, as **k** refers to **asterisk** character, and **n** refers to user defined **number**), you can easily solve this problem. Give it a shot, and have fun :)

*Edit:* *pseudo-code sample can be something like the following:*

```
int function getnumber();
int function factorial(n);

void function putstar(k)
{ 
   counter = factorial(n) / (factorial(k) * factorial(n - k));
   For(i=0; i < counter; ++i)
      print("*");
   print(new_line);
}

int function Main()
{
   n = getnumber();
   For(i=0; i <= n; ++i)
      putstar(i);
   print(new_line);
   exit();
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot , this exactly what I've been looking for... now I build an elegant firm code that is based upon correct understanding to the problem...

Comment: sorry Bora for bothering you but could u at least suggest a snippet or a pseudo code for the suggested algorithm... thanks in advance

Comment: it's ok, no problem. I added a pseudo-code sample to the answer. Good luck.